# AngularJs template url

Tags: angularjs

If I should use

```
templateUrl: 'Content/Custom/Login.html'
```

it will work only when user is in `Home/Index` controller. And it should not if user will be at another controller something like `Home/About`.

> http://localhost:7602/Home/Content/Custom/Login.html Failed to load
>   resource:

Because template is situated in

```
http://localhost:7602/Content/Custom/Login.html
```

How to fix this? What is the right way of template declaration?

```
$mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'Content/Custom/Login.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        fullscreen: useFullScreen
    })
    .then(function (answer) {
        $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
    }, function () {
        $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
    });
```

Comment: Have you defined `<base href="/">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Absolute Path to your partials

for instance If your app is in App Directory than use:

```
templateUrl: '/App/Content/Custom/Login.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare somewhere in your _Layout.cshtml

```js
<script>
        window.contentUrl = @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Content("~/Content/"), true));
</script>
```

Then use it in your templateUrl as

```js
templateUrl: contentUrl + "/Custom/Login.html'
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, but relies on ASP.NET Razor, which wasn't mentioned in the question.